# I incessantly get errors

Tags: python

I always get AssertionError. Before putting the assert line, I was getting unsupported operand type for / error.

```
def faktoriyel(a):
    assert a==int,"a is not a number"
    a = int(a)
    total = 1
    
    for i in range(1,int(a+1)):
        total *= i


        return total
    
    
    
for x in range (5,11):
    x = int(x)
    a = faktoriyel(x-3)
    b = faktoriyel(x+1)
    c = faktoriyel(x-2)
    d = faktoriyel(x)
    uc = faktoriyel(3)
    if d/a == 4 * b/(uc*c):
                                  istenen = x

return istenen
```

I was trying to create a problem solver.

Comment: Please extract a [mcve], it's going to look like `assert 1 == int`. Problem is, `1` is an instance of `int`, but the two are not the same. One is an actual value, the other is the type which all integers share. Please, as a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: To check if a is an int you can use either: 1) assert isinstance(a, int), "a is not a number"  or  2) assert type(a) is int, "a is not a number"

Comment: Did you noticed that `faktoriyel` always return 1?

Comment: Your return should be after the for loop (i.e,. not within).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few key issues which can be glanced at once:

1. The return statement is indented to inside for statement which will return result for 1st iteration here 1
2. you are asserting a as `int` instead of asserting its instance `assert isinstance(a, int), "a is not a number"`

Corrected "faktoriyel" function

```
    def faktoriyel(a):
        assert isinstance(a, int), "a is not a number"
        total = 1
    
        for i in range(1, a + 1):
            total *= i

        return total
```

Fixed whole code

```
def faktoriyel(a):
    assert isinstance(a, int), "a is not a number"
    total = 1
    
    for i in range(1, a + 1):
        total *= i

    return total

istenen = 0

for x in range(5, 11):
    a = faktoriyel(x - 3)
    b = faktoriyel(x + 1)
    c = faktoriyel(x - 2)
    d = faktoriyel(x)
    uc = faktoriyel(3)
    
    if d / a == 4 * b / (uc * c):
        istenen = x
        break

print(istenen)
```